# Combining the contents of two C# message boxes into one

Tags: c#, messagebox

I have the following code shown below in my program. One of the message boxes pops up to display the contents of field forms. After hitting OK, another one pops up asking the user if the information is correct. I would like to combine the two where the message box will pop up displaying the form contents and asking if the information is correct, accompanied by a YES/NO button. I've tried combining the two to no avail. I believe I am missing a syntactical concept.  Any ideas?

```
   //shows contents of form fields
  StringBuilder MessageText = new StringBuilder();
        MessageText.AppendLine(string.Format("Coil#: {0}", coil_Num.Text));
        MessageText.AppendLine(string.Format("Location: {0}", location_box.Text));
        MessageText.AppendLine(string.Format("Sub-Area: {0}", sub_area_box.Text));
        MessageText.AppendLine(string.Format("Row: {0}", row_Num.Text));
        MessageBox.Show(MessageText.ToString());

  //asks if info is correct, with a YES/NO button and question mark
  DialogResult result1 = MessageBox.Show("Information is correct?",
        "Double Check Form Information",
        MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel,
        MessageBoxIcon.Question);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 //shows contents of form fields
  StringBuilder MessageText = new StringBuilder();
        MessageText.AppendLine(string.Format("Coil#: {0}", coil_Num.Text));
        MessageText.AppendLine(string.Format("Location: {0}", location_box.Text));
        MessageText.AppendLine(string.Format("Sub-Area: {0}", sub_area_box.Text));
        MessageText.AppendLine(string.Format("Row: {0}", row_Num.Text));
        MessageText.AppendLine();
        MessageText.AppendLine();

  //asks if info is correct, with a YES/NO button and question mark
  DialogResult result1 = MessageBox.Show(MessageText.ToString() + "Information is correct?",
        "Double Check Form Information",
        MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel,
        MessageBoxIcon.Question);
```

Something like this? Of course this last text could also be appended to the StringBuilder.

If you only want Yes/No buttons then change `MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel` to `MessageBoxButtons.YesNo`.

Finally check the result like this:

```
switch (result1)
{
   case DialogResult.Yes:
      // ... Do stuff if Yes is choosen
      break;

   case DialogResult.No:
      // ... Do stuff if No is choosen
      break;

   case DialogResult.Cancel:
      // ... Do stuff if Cancel is choosen
      break;
}
```

of course you have to add/remove the cancel option depending on if you include the button or not.

Comment: Yea that is exactly what I needed. I didn't think to add in the two appendline()s. Thank you very much!

Comment: Check my edit :) Also you could do the `AppendLine` and `string.Format()` in one line with `StringBuilder.AppendFormat()`

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to ask the question after the information, in which case it's a matter of appending your question to the stringbuilder before passing to the relevant MessageBox arg as you were in the first MessageBox:

```
StringBuilder MessageText = new StringBuilder();
MessageText.AppendLine(string.Format("Coil#: {0}", coil_Num.Text));
MessageText.AppendLine(string.Format("Location: {0}", location_box.Text));
MessageText.AppendLine(string.Format("Sub-Area: {0}", sub_area_box.Text));
MessageText.AppendLine(string.Format("Row: {0}", row_Num.Text));
MessageText.AppendLine("Is this information correct?");

DialogResult result1 = MessageBox.Show(MessageText.ToString(),
    "Double Check Form Information",
    MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel,
    MessageBoxIcon.Question);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
MessageBox.Show(MessageText.ToString(), MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
```

The 2nd argument (MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel) is what determines what buttons it will have (in this case, yes, no, and cancel)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply concatenate the strings?

```
    DialogResult result1 = MessageBox.Show(MessageText.ToString() + 
"\nInformation is correct?",
        "Double Check Form Information",
        MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel,
        MessageBoxIcon.Question);
```